# Tool to monitor wifi stability?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

I'm having wireless problems both at home and at work.
I'm looking for a tool that tests

1. TCP/IP reliability: wireless network is always here
2. bandwidth: does the bandwidth drop at some point?
3. (maybe) if DNS works reliably

The tool should work on Windows or Mac or Linux. Doesn't really matter.

**[Edit]**
To clarify: In the end I want either some graphs that show up/downtime or just a number in percentage of the time I run the monitor.
This way I can run the monitor for some days, do some changes in the Wifi config and can see if it has helped for the better or for the worse.

Answer (score 5):

What i check first and foremost is interference with other neighbouring channels and routers tranmitting there and how it affects your signal strength...

So check Netstumbler or even better inSSIDer to perform your site survey at a first level of diagnostics...Own Android device? Check WiFi analyzer app...or http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/meraki-wifi-stumbler_ixku.html

To dig event deeper you can turn to raw packet/wi-fi traffic capture tools and traffic analyzers (wireshark/ethereal, MS Network monitor to name a few).

Also worth mentioning for further troubleshooting is Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector.

At a more practical level:

- avoid using microwave and Wi-fi at the same time
- avoid using 2.4 GHz cordless phones
- search for better antenna(s)
- reinstall or upgrade drivers
- install latest device firmware

Also, event logs are your friend...maybe setup a Snare syslog agent ([http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/BackLogNT/](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/meraki-wifi-stumbler_ixku.html)) and collect info across your hosts...That will definitely provide a wider perspective on what happens, the time it happens and help you see a pattern maybe repeating...

Comment: This was not quite what I was looking for. I added a clarification in the question. Thanks anyway, lots of useful content here, just not for my situation.. I have installed the Wifi analyzer already and it helps to see on which channel is which AP and their signal strength. All the logging tools are too much work - I don't want to build the tool myself but just start up a program that does measure all the important metrics for me.